# Service in Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

I am working on an application(**minSDK = 19 & targetSDK = 26**) in which there are 20 services for e.g. services like MediaPlayer, SyncUpData and SyncDownData etc. As **Android O** doesn't allow long running background services. I'm quite confused that what to choose between JobScheduler, FirebaseJobDispature, JobIntentService etc. because JobShecduler introduced in API 21 and FirebaseJobDispature in API 14.

Another question is how to check which services are need to be replaced with above framework and which are not.

There are 3 services that should be running even if the application is not visible because these service sends/receives data packets to/from bluetooth device. They will stop running either on application kill or manually disconnects the connection.

I know there are lots of solution online but I'm confused which I should use.

Please suggest the suitable solution for this. 
TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to use is the new [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager) library.
It wraps all the possible API level scenarios:

> - Uses JobScheduler for API 23+
> - For API 14-22 If using Firebase JobDispatcher in the app and the optional Firebase dependency, uses Firebase JobDispatcher
> - Otherwise, uses a custom AlarmManager +
>     BroadcastReceiver implementation

In addition, [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/services-the-life-with-without-and-worker-6933111d62a6) some literature and usage examples for it.

The WorkManager use case is only for background jobs which require guaranteed execution, even after the app gets killed.

If instead you need a Foreground service, then is as simple as creating it yourself by extending the [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) class. For Oreo you will need to show a UI notificaiton. Then the service can be started as foreground with the next call:

```
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, yourService);
```

Though if the service lives only while the app is active, and stopped manually through the app or whenever the app exists, then instead you should consider using a Thread and not a service.

[Quote](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) from the android documentation:

> If you need to perform work outside your main thread, but only while the user is interacting with your application, then you should probably instead create a new thread and not a service. For example, if you want to play some music, but only while your activity is running, you might create a thread in onCreate(), start running it in onStart(), then stop it in onStop(). Also consider using AsyncTask or HandlerThread, instead of the traditional Thread class. See the Processes and Threading document for more information about threads.
>
> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking operations.

Comment: I just ran the application without any changes on android O and it's working fine. onStartService() is working. any idea about this??

Comment: Could you clarify? you mean exactly as you wrote that is working? you didn't expect it to work? or is a typo and you mean is not working?

Comment: I haven't made any changes you suggested related to WorkManager or anything else but still the service is running on Oreo device.

Comment: Your question is about what Service to choose, the answer is the WorkManager. which is a wrapper for all the services. With it you don't need to worry about which service to use, if the JobShecduler, the JobIntentService, or any other, etc. Also you don't need to worry if any gets deprecated. The WorkManager as a wrapper is the perfect replacement for all of them. Internally it chooses the best service based on the current API level. Of course, you may still use whatever service you want, and it may work, but then you need to think if it will get deprecated or if it works in all API levels.

Comment: how to identify which service will work as forground or background service??

Comment: There's service DataDownload which downloads data from server.A timertask which is scheduled to run at fixed time interval in this service which checks the availablity of data and downloads. What should I do in this case??

Comment: If all these operations are required only while the application is active (open), then probably these should be changed to be Threads and not Services, a HandlerThread would a good candidate. If instead, these operations need to run even when the app is closed, and by your requirements seems there is no need for a foreground service, then the WorkManager.PeriodicWorkRequest would be the path to go.

Comment: I tried to run a service on Android Oreo and it’s working okay. I mean according to android docs, a service won’t run long in background but I tried the same and its working fine. I am using Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android Oreo).

Could you please suggest how to reproduce this? @PerracoLabs

Comment: Without the code is difficult to guess. Evaluate if the service is instead being started as foreground. Take into account that it will be the OS which will decide when to kill the service, so you shouldn't code based only in the experience of 1 model, otherwise you will get a bad surprise when releasing the product and start to see failures in other different device models. And as mentioned, if the service runs only while the app is open then should be a thread. If instead, it runs even when the app is closed and executing in time intervals, then the WorkManager is the best solution.

Comment: I created a sample workmanager project, in which a periodicTaskRequest is defined to run at interval of 15 min. But it only runs for the first time when I launch the app, after 15 min it doesn't work. any idea??

Comment: This needs to be a completely new question published in Stakoverflow, so it doesn't mix with this one. And would recommend that in the question you publish the sample of how you create the WorkManager so we can understand better why it fails.